# npm install SyntaxError: Unexpected token C

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, homebrew

I made some changes to the npm configuration in the previous days, and now I consistently receive the same error while trying to install any of a variety of packages. Essentially, I cannot utilize npm anymore due to what I think is a personal erroneous change to npm settings.

I have uninstalled node and npm, and re-installed, and tried the configuration settings in the npm blog, and I still get the same error. Perhaps it has to do with permissions in Cellar directory? I thought I had taken care of that previously...

It is not clear to me what is the issue and would appreciate your help very much.

Error output is below:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token C
npm ERR! Cannot GET http://registry.npmjs.org/node-simple-router
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient. (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:203:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:123:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request. (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:893:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage. (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:844:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!
```

The output of `npm config list` generates:

```
$ npm config list
; cli configs
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; userconfig /Users/rfatahi/.npmrc
ca = ""
https-proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"
proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = true

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "/usr/local"

; node bin location = /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/bin/node
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open file `/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js`, and insert `console.log(data)` on the line 202 (just before `JSON.parse`, you will be able to see what error are you getting.

You can also get the npm configuration using `npm config list` and post it, or just remove your *npmrc* file. But I'm not sure it's a configuration issue.

Also, it's strange that you make a request over HTTP, since default URL is HTTPS. Maybe some firewall is screwing things up(?).

Comment: yes, i was playing around with tunnel and proxy, and then received such. Thanks for your feedback, I'm going to be going through the outline you provided now.

Comment: the console log now includes `Cannot GET http://registry.npmjs.org/http` and edited to include the npm config list in request above. certainly looks like a firewall issue, probably from nginx

Comment: So your express-based proxy returns `Cannot GET http://registry.npmjs.org/http`. If it's not intentional, you can just run `npm config set proxy null` to turn it off.

Comment: I saw the same error locally. It was caused by the http request to our internal npm server returning 404 response with data. The response data was 'Cannot GET /-/all' referring to a standard JSON URL when requesting npm search. I'm surprised the npm error handling doesn't handle the 404 result better, it only initially checks that the result is not 304 before attempting to parse the result as JSON. The 'Unexpected token C' refers to the first character in the http response 'Cannot'. npm config set proxy null did not fix this issue.